# Ошибка при загрузке картинки в vue-cropperjs

Tags: vue.js

Есть картинка

```
<img :src="vacancyLogo" ref='vLogo'/>

data () {
  vacancyLogo: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test.new.vcv.ru/test5-new.vcv.ru/vacancies/4185/logo_2018-11-23T09%3A17%3A10.277Z'
}
```

Используется vue-cropperjs, передаю этот src

```
this.$refs.cropper.replace(this.vacancyLogo)
```

Возвращается ошибка

> Access to image at 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test.new.vcv.ru/test5-new.vcv.ru/vacancies/4185/logo_2018-11-23T09%3A17%3A10.277Z?timestamp=1542966387614' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Почему возникает такая ошибка?
Или я не так передаю url?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает потому что вы грузите картинку с другого хоста. Нужно чтобы этот хост возвращал заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin, в котором указано каким хостам можно это делать. Для этого в nginx можно сделать вот так

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://your-front-host.lh;
```

Тут описано подробнее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: Спасибо, помогло